# failed to accept incoming connection winsock2

Tags: c++, winsock2

My code is working well in console application. Now I am trying to embed it with GUI by using `wxDev`. Sequence is:

1. `virtual char* start()=0;`
2. `virtual char* version()=0;`
3. `virtual char* creat()=0;`
4. `virtual char* bin()=0;`
5. `virtual char* lis()=0;`
6. `virtual char* acc()=0;`

From 0 to 4 all functions are working good,
when `acc()` accept function is called it dose not respond. My code:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <winsock.h>
int inn=100;
char error[]={":::::I M HERE::::::"};
char chaa[]={"Inside LIKE FUNCTION.\n"};
char st[]={"Starting...\n"};
char ve[]={"Compatable Verstion.\n"};
char cr[]={"Socket Created.\n"};
char bi[]={"Binding Done.\n"};
char li[]={"Listeng..........\n"};
char ac[]={"Connected..........\n"};
int WSAStartup(WORD wVersionRequested, LPWSADATA lpWSAData);
SOCKET socket(int af, int type, int protocol);
int connect(SOCKET s, const struct sockaddr *name, int namelen);
int bind(SOCKET s, const struct sockaddr *name, int namelen);
int listen(SOCKET s, int backlog);

class Server 
{
public:
SOCKET sockh;
SOCKET socka;
WSADATA wsadata;
sockaddr_in sockAddr, client;
public:

char* like(){return chaa;}
int kiss(){return inn++;}
virtual char* start()=0;
virtual char* version()=0;
virtual char* creat()=0;
virtual char* bin()=0;
virtual char* lis()=0;
//virtual char* acc()=0; 
};

class startup: public Server
{
public:
char* start(){
if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsadata)==0)
    return st; 
}
};
class ver:public startup{
public:
    char* version(){
        if(LOBYTE(wsadata.wVersion)>=2)
            return ve;
        } 
};
class created: public ver   {
public:
    char* creat(){
        if(socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)!=INVALID_SOCKET)
        return cr;
        }
};
class binded: public created{
public:
// Bind socket to port 80
    char* bin()
    {
//        sockaddr_in sockAddr;
sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockAddr.sin_port = htons(7777);
sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
if (bind(sockh, (sockaddr*)(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr))!=0)
        return bi;
        } 
};
class listenn: public binded
    {
  public:
    char* lis(){
        if(listen(sockh, SOMAXCONN)!=0)
            {
                     return li;                  
                        }
            }
 };
 class accep: public listenn{
public:
char* acc(){
int siz=sizeof(client);
socka=accept(sockh,reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&sockAddr),&siz);
if(socka!=INVALID_SOCKET)
return ac;
else return error;
}
};
```

I have also tried by avoiding return statments in same class.

```
SOCKET sockh;
SOCKET socka;
WSADATA wsadata;
sockaddr_in sockAddr, client;

if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsadata)==0)
{
 if(LOBYTE(wsadata.wVersion)>=2)
 {
  if(socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)!=INVALID_SOCKET)
  {

sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockAddr.sin_port = htons(7777);
sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
if (bind(sockh, (sockaddr*)(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr))!=0)        
    {
           if(listen(sockh, SOMAXCONN)!=0)
            {
                //waiting for incoming connection
              int siz=sizeof(client);
                socka=accept(sockh,reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>     (&sockAddr),&siz);
                    if(socka!=INVALID_SOCKET)
                    {
                        return "Connected...";
                        }
                }            
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that invokes the sequence? I don't get why you implement each method in a separate class.

Comment: i also tried it in single class,

Comment: The problem is obvious but you don't accept any help as it seems. In both code snippets you never use the created socket because you simply ignore the returned socket descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

You never set the variable `sockh`. You should assign the return value of `socket` to it:

```
if((sockh = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
   return cr;
```

Furthermore, you don't check the return values correctly. `bind` and `listen` return `0` on success.

**Edit:**

Because it seems to be incomprehensible, here the entire code that works as expected:

```
class startup: public Server {
  public:
  char* start(){
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsadata)==0)
      return st; 
  }
};

class ver:public startup {
  public:
  char* version(){
    if(LOBYTE(wsadata.wVersion)>=2)
      return ve;
  } 
};

class created: public ver {
  public:
  char* creat() {
    if((sockh=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP))!=INVALID_SOCKET)
      return cr;
  }
};

class binded: public created {
public:
  // Bind socket to port 80
  char* bin() {
    //        sockaddr_in sockAddr;
    sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockAddr.sin_port = htons(7777);
    sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    if (bind(sockh, (sockaddr*)(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr))==0)
      return bi;
  } 
};

class listenn: public binded {
public:
  char* lis() {
    if(listen(sockh, SOMAXCONN)==0)
      return li;                  
  }
};

class accep: public listenn {
public:
  char* acc() {
    int siz=sizeof(client);
    socka=accept(sockh,reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&sockAddr),&siz);
    if(socka!=INVALID_SOCKET)
      return ac;
    else return error;
  }
};
```

By the way, if people investigate their time given assistance, one should try to follow their suggestions and accept the requested help.

Comment: i used socka instead of sock. and this code succesfully listen to a socket but it dose not accept any connection and halt on

Comment: But all your calls before `accept` work on `sockh` and it is never initialized. And the code only listen "successfully" because your check of the return value is wrong.

Comment: do you mean that i should follow sockh from startup to accept function instead of socka ? same sock handler for all functions ?

Comment: My answer contains a suggestion how you could change your `socket` creation. You should assign the return value of the `socket` function to `sockh`.